# Initialising dim3 variables in CUDA, how does the "dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);" syntax work?

Tags: c++, syntax, cuda, initialization

I'm learning CUDA, and in plenty of example code I see block and grid dimensions being set like this:

```
dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);
dim3 dimBlock(numThreadsPerBlock);
exampleKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(input);
```

I understand that a line like `dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);` is initialising dimGrid, a variable of dim3 type, to have `numBlocks` as its x value - but I'm not sure how this works.

I would have just assumed it was normal C++ syntax, but for C++ I thought that the line has to be written like this:

```
dim3 dimGrid = dim3(numBlocks);
```

Otherwise you get "the most vexing parse". So I'm assuming that the interpretation of those lines as a variable assignment is special behaviour by CUDA's NVCC compiler, but I can't find anything that confirms this.

Am I right that this is what is happening, or is there something else I don't understand about how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal C++ syntax. You only get the (most) vexing parse if the parentheses are empty or contain a type (followed by parentheses). In your case, `numBlocks` is not a type so all is well.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that there were those conditions on the vexing parse problem.

Comment: @AdamGoodwin The (most) vexing parse means that the expression is misinterpreted as a function declaration. So it has to be a valid function declaration for this to happen.

Answer (score 5):

This is normal C++ syntax, you can try it yourself with a minimal working example.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int _x;
public:
    A(int x) : _x(x) {}
    int x() const { return _x; }
};

int main() {
    A first(3);
    cout << first.x() << endl; // "3"
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.